# Applying more than two CIFilter over the CALayer

Tags: swift, calayer, core-image, cifilter

I am trying to make Canvas with CIFilter's for UIImageView. In my application user should have opportunity retouch his photo using UIPanGesture (Adding UIBezierPath to CALayer).
But I've faced with a problem. I have no idea how to add more then one filter during user interaction with UIImageView because it can't be transparent and **CALayer should contains CIImage for retouch (I am trying to find way to avoid it).**

*Example: Add whiten and skin smooth*
Now I have something like:

- UIImageView
- - WhitenLayer with opacity and image with filter in contents
- - SmoothLayer with opacity and source image with filter in contents

And it is looks bad.

Answer (score -1):

Solved using backgroundFilters and multiplyCompositing